# What should the watering schedule for garlic be to ensure optimal growth?

Tags: watering, garlic

I'm wondering if I should personally water garlic every day in the spring, or just let mother nature take care of it for the most part so it can grow big quickly, then allow it to do its own stuff over the summer/fall.

Comment: Where are you (Zone and sunlight hours, latitude might help), and can we assume you are not looking for commercial-scale type options.   I can't comment specifically on Garlic, but I expect that the ideal amount of water will depend on the amount of heat and light the plants receive - ie the more heat and/or light, the more frequently they need to be watered.  According to http://www.mitre10.co.nz/guides_and_advice/gardening_guides/how_to_grow_garlic/ Garlic likes to be kept moist (but well drained) - and you should reduce the amount of water 1 month before harvest to improve the quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Let the soil dry out a bit before watering. Dig down 1 inch into the soil. If the 1 inch of soil is dry, water it.
2. If the leaves are wilting, or "deflated", it needs water. I mention deflated leaves for onions and garlics because they are round, hollow, and structurally strong, so they may not literally fall over until they are near death from lack of water.
3. In general I water all my garden in the morning to reduce mold and fungus, but I don't have a special problem with fungi. My soil is loamy so it drains very well.
4. If you water in the evenings and don't have any mold problems, just continue what you're doing.
5. It will do better if you give it enough water. In Michigan most summers, we get very little water in July and August. It's rare if the sidewalks get barely all the way dark and wet in those months. That's when I water stuff. So your watering schedule depends on your weather too.
6. I naturally let my onions die off in August, the hottest part of the year. That's normal for this cool weather plant and does not harm it.

Answer (score 5):

Would not water every day, you can create problems. You can for one: kill the plant, there would not be any air going to the plants root and would kill of the roots. two: You could grow mold around the plant and on the plant. In the end killing it as well, plus then you would have to toss out the dirt to stop it from spreading.